# Empty nodes in tensorboard profile

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I used GPU profiling functionality in tensorflow with code like this:

```
run_opts = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
meta = tf.RunMetadata()
sess.run(op, options=run_opts, run_metadata=meta)
writer.add_run_metadata(meta, 'profile')
writer.flush()
```

Unfortunately, when I load it in the tensorboard, I see a lot of empty boxes like on the attached image.

What's wrong? How can I work around:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. In the left pane you should choose device. Then you should choose gpu:0. It's definitely a usability problem in tensorboard.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is due to an `trace input` option you selected in tensorboard.

[image]

Take a look at the [video here](https://youtu.be/eBbEDRsCmv4?t=7m50s), when a guy selects this option, the image looks like the one you linked here.